# Rest API filter syntax error

Tags: client-object-model, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

i am getting invalid error on the below error. I couldnt make out what the error was.

```
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mega Menu')/items?$select=Sub_x0020_Heading$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq " + heading + ")",
```

Error

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The expression \\\"Sub_x0020_Heading$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY)\\\" is not valid.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"Sub_x0020_Heading$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY)\" is not valid."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: it will be helpful if u provide the error details here. and did u tried in your browser with this rest uri.

Comment: Updated as advised.

Comment: Try like this in `$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq '" + heading + "')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the ampersand(`&`) before `filter` operator.

Modify it as below:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mega Menu')/items?
$select=Sub_x0020_Heading&$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq " + heading + ")",
```

Comment: almost i got the output except one main heading field has 'CONTRACTS & LEGAL'. I think the & is making the issue. is there any way to get over it.

Comment: Modify it as `&$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq " + encodeURIComponent(heading) + ")",` and check

Comment: that solves the problem. if its not too much. i need to order it with a field "Sub Heading Order" can you advise how to?

Comment: Cheers, happy to help :) , you can accept it as answer( by ticking the checkmark) so that it wont show up for us in the unanswered section and optionally upvote it !